# Unix shell script to GET_DDL and create table SNOWFLAKES

Tags: unix, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to GET_DDL of snowflake table and recreate it using Unix shell script. Please help me.

Query for get DDL : select GET_DDL('TABLE','TABLENAME',TRUE);

Comment: As in are you looking to run the DDL statements for existing objects and then build it as a shell script -> use that to run and build the objects on a new account?

Comment: I appreciate if you could help with the sample shell script

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of good examples in the following community links:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007LgoXqSAJ/unix-shell-script-to-connect-cli-snow-sql

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007ZBOZnSAP/snowsql-through-shell-script

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007sLjaqSAC/shell-script-calls-sql-file-with-variables

https://dwgeek.com/how-to-execute-snowflake-commands-from-shell-script-example.html/